# Does anyone really know how dark energy/matter works?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, dark-matter, dark-energy, matter

If [dark energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_energy) has no physical interaction with normal matter but it does interact with [dark matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_matter), wouldn't that cause an interaction with normal matter through its interaction with dark matter and dark matters subsequent interaction with normal matter? Can dark matter interact with normal matter without the presence of dark energy or is dark energy what allows the interaction (like an unknown catalyst)?
Or am I on an unanswerable tangent without first understanding dark energy?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Don't be misled by the coincidence in labels - dark matter and dark energy are entirely different phenomena. Think of them as "pink" matter and "fluffy" energy.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sijNG.png

Answer (score 4):

Dark matter and dark energy are completely separate notions. Dark matter is regular matter in the sense that it interacts gravitationally with visible matter in a consistent manner. It is dark because it doesn't interact electromagnetically or at least interacts negligibly (as far as we can tell) so we literally cannot see it. Since weak (nuclear) and strong interactions are short range, we can't deduce whether it's some sort of particle that interacts in that way either. The only way we can tell it exists is outer orbits of celestial bodies in some galaxies.

Dark energy on the other hand does not interact with anything. You can view it as a form of energy that permeates physical space itself and exists everywhere uniformly. The current most plausible explanation is that dark energy is (for the most part) vacuum potential energy, which for Einstein gravity corresponds to a cosmological constant. The result is that it causes the Universe to expand in an accelerated manner, leading asymptotically to a curved (de Sitter) space - assuming it continues, of course. That we can also observe.

Answer (score -3):

Dark energy is the outflow of dark matter along the pole of our Universe's central black hole. Our Universe is a larger version of our Milky Way galaxy. Our Milky Way galaxy has outflows along the poles which push the gas far beyond the extent of our galaxy. Our Universe's central black hole pushes the galaxies far beyond the extent of our Universe's central black hole.

Dark matter is the spacetime fabric. Dark matter is ubiquitous. Dark matter is displaced by ordinary matter. What is referred to geometrically as curved spacetime physically exists as displaced dark matter. The dark matter displaced by the Earth, pushing back and exerting pressure toward the Earth, forces you to the Earth. Displaced dark matter 'displaces back', causing gravity.

Comment: A fun bit of creative writing! Too bad it has nothing to do with accepted notions of physics & cosmology.